# Copying new rows and certain changes from one SQL DB table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two databases on different servers. I've created a link between the two and am wanting to insert new data and specific changed data on timed intervals, one-way, with a few caveats (If it was just a straight, one-time copy, I'd have no issue). For example:

Table 1 columns to be copied: ID, H, W, D, Name, WO, RM, QTY, PN.

Table 2 will have the same columns, plus: Stage, SD.

I need to, on timed intervals, copy the data from Table1 to Table2. The ID is unique and it needs to check if any other of the originally copied data changed, and if it did, replace it with the new data as well as add new rows. What it cannot do it replace data in the additional columns in Table2, even if some of the original data has changed.

**UPDATE (EXAMPLE)**

```
Table1

ID      H   W   D   Name    WO      RM     QTY  PN
40101   32  32  12  Prod1   9501    Front   1   23.1
40102   12  12  6   Prod2   9501    Back    19  29.5
40103   18  36  12  Prod3   9502    Side    5   43.3


Table2

ID      H   W   D   Name    WO      RM      QTY PN      Stage       SD
40101   32  32  12  Prod1   9501    Front   1   23.1    2018-02-15  2018-02-22
40102   12  12  6   Prod2   9501    Back    19  29.5    2018-02-16  2018-02-22
40103   18  36  12  Prod3   9502    Side    5   43.3    2018-02-16  2018-02-22
```

As shown above, Table1 data is copied to Table2 through SQL insert query; there are more columns in Table1 than what is shown, but those are the only columns included. There will be times that the data changes for a row in Table1, possibly just one column or maybe all of them except ID. When copying the data to Table2, it should insert new records, update the columns that have changed (only ones copied from Table1) in existing rows and not others columns in Table2 that may or may not already have data in them, such as the Stage or SD column in Table2.

Comment: can u please add some sample data and expected columns in both tables

Comment: Certainly, give me a few minutes and I'll update.

Comment: You need all this, and we need to see what have you tried first? Where are you blocked? What did you achieve so far?

Comment: Are you happy with how Table1 updates or do u need to write query for populating table1 from remote server ?

Comment: Table1 is populated by software and will only be used as the source. It will only ever be a one-way insert/update from Table1 > Table2.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Merge` Procedure is best approach in this case. This works, but also depends on any constraints on source and destination tables. Merge proc is always optimized if your tables are aligned properly with `data types , constraints`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TableInsert_Update
AS
BEGIN
    MERGE Table2 AS TARGET
    USING Table1 AS SOURCE
        ON (TARGET.id = SOURCE.id)
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN
            UPDATE
            SET TARGET.col1 = SOURCE.col1
                ,TARGET.col2 = SOURCE.col2
                ,TARGET.col3 = SOURCE.col3
                ,TARGET.col4 = SOURCE.col4
                --add more columns      
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN
            INSERT (
                col1
                ,col2
                ,col3
                ,col4
                )
            --add more columns  
            VALUES (
                SOURCE.col1
                ,SOURCE.col2
                ,SOURCE.col3
                ,SOURCE.col4
                --add more columns
                );
END
```